# regex extract tableau

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I am trying to create a regex extract function in tableau.
When I use the regex match function, everything works, but the same formula for extract doesn't work. Thoughts?

```
REGEXP_MATCH([Comments Keyed In By User],
             '.*(|SC)( |)([0-9][0-9][0-9])( - | | -|-|)([0-9][0-9]|).*')
```

vs

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Comments Keyed In By User],
               '.*(|SC)( |)([0-9][0-9][0-9])( - | | -|-|)([0-9][0-9]|).*')
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What are sample texts you need to match/extract?

Comment: It doesn't extract any data at all. The column is blank.  I need to extract data like SC919 or SC-934 or SC 434 in a long sentence od data

Comment: Try `REGEXP_EXTRACT([Comments Keyed In By User], 'SC[- ]*[0-9]{3}')` (or the regex can also have word boundaries - `'\bSC[- ]*\d{3}\b'`)

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: No. I am getting only null values in tableau

Comment: I understood the problem. It's a Tableau Issue. You have to enclose in parenthesis; thanks for all your help anyway!

Comment: Great, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `.*` around the pattern when you *extract*  the matches, and it seems Tableau requires the capturing group to be defined in the pattern to actually get the text into the results.

Use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Comments Keyed In By User], '(SC[- ]*[0-9]{3})')
```

**Details**:

- `SC` - matches `SC` substring
- `[- ]*` - zero or more `-` or spaces (replace `*` with `?` to match one or zero occurrences)
- `[0-9]{3}` - 3 digits

To match whole words only, enclose the pattern with word boundaries `\b`: `'\b(SC[- ]*[0-9]{3})\b'`.